Do ref parameters need special handling in source generated native marshaling?
I was playing around with this new feature and decided to use dbghelp.dll's SymGetModuleInfo64 as an example. I wrote the custom marshaller and I am able to run it (below is the generated code), but it throws an AccessViolationException when the result of ConvertToManaged is assigned back to the ref. Does the ref parameter need special handling? Currently I am just instantiating a IMAGEHELP_MODULE64 and setting its SizeOfStruct before passing it to SymGetModuleInfo64.
    public unsafe partial class Test
    {
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Interop.LibraryImportGenerator", "7.0.10.26716")]
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.SkipLocalsInitAttribute]
        private static partial bool SymGetModuleInfo64(nint hProcess, long ModuleBase64, ref global::Test.Test.IMAGEHELP_MODULE64 imgHelpModule)
        {
            int __lastError;
            global::Test.Test.IMAGEHELP_MODULE64_Marshaller.Unmanaged __imgHelpModule_native;
            bool __retVal;
            int __retVal_native;
            // Marshal - Convert managed data to native data.
            __imgHelpModule_native = global::Test.Test.IMAGEHELP_MODULE64_Marshaller.ConvertToUnmanaged(imgHelpModule);
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SetLastSystemError(0);
                __retVal_native = __PInvoke(hProcess, ModuleBase64, &__imgHelpModule_native);
                __lastError = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
            }

            // Unmarshal - Convert native data to managed data.
            __retVal = __retVal_native != 0;
----->      imgHelpModule = global::Test.Test.IMAGEHELP_MODULE64_Marshaller.ConvertToManaged(__imgHelpModule_native);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SetLastPInvokeError(__lastError);
            return __retVal;
            // Local P/Invoke
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("dbghelp.dll", EntryPoint = "SymGetModuleInfo64", ExactSpelling = true)]
            static extern unsafe int __PInvoke(nint hProcess, long ModuleBase64, global::Test.Test.IMAGEHELP_MODULE64_Marshaller.Unmanaged* imgHelpModule);
        }
    }

I tried allocating memory for the parameter, to ensure I own it, but no matter what I do I still get the AccessViolationException.
Here's what the Test class that generated the code above looks like (NOTE: I was only interested in the LoadedPdbName so I didn't implement marshalling for the entire struct, but that shouldn't matter, the PInvoke call succeeds):
public unsafe partial class Test
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    [NativeMarshalling(typeof(IMAGEHELP_MODULE64_Marshaller))]
    private struct IMAGEHELP_MODULE64
    {
        public int SizeOfStruct;
        public long BaseOfImage;
        public int ImageSize;
        public int TimeDateStamp;
        public int CheckSum;
        public int NumSyms;
        public SymType SymType;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string ModuleName;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string ImageName;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string LoadedImageName;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string LoadedPdbName;

        public int CVSig;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 780)]
        public string CVData;

        public int PdbSig;
        public GUID PdbSig70;
        public int PdbAge;
        public bool PdbUnmatched;
        public bool DbgUnmatched;
        public bool LineNumbers;
        public bool GlobalSymbols;
        public bool TypeInfo;
        public bool SourceIndexed;
        public bool Publics;
        public int MachineType;
        public int Reserved;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct GUID
    {
        public int Data1;
        public ushort Data2;
        public ushort Data3;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public byte[] data4;
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum SymType : uint
    {
        SymNone,
        SymCoff,
        SymCv,
        SymPdb,
        SymExport,
        SymDeferred,
        SymSym,
        SymDia,
        SymVirtual,
    }

    [CustomMarshaller(typeof(IMAGEHELP_MODULE64), MarshalMode.Default, typeof(IMAGEHELP_MODULE64_Marshaller))]
    private static unsafe class IMAGEHELP_MODULE64_Marshaller
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public ref struct Unmanaged
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)] public int SizeOfStruct;
            [FieldOffset(580)] public fixed byte LoadedPdbName[256];
        }

        public static Unmanaged ConvertToUnmanaged(IMAGEHELP_MODULE64 managed)
        {
            return new Unmanaged
            {
                SizeOfStruct = managed.SizeOfStruct
            };
        }

        public static IMAGEHELP_MODULE64 ConvertToManaged(Unmanaged unmanaged)
        {
            return new IMAGEHELP_MODULE64
            {
                LoadedPdbName = AnsiStringMarshaller.ConvertToManaged(unmanaged.LoadedPdbName)
            };
        }
    }

    [LibraryImport("dbghelp.dll", StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf8, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static partial bool SymGetModuleInfo64(nint hProcess, long ModuleBase64,
        ref IMAGEHELP_MODULE64 imgHelpModule);
}

And here's how it's being used:
var moduleInfo = new IMAGEHELP_MODULE64();
moduleInfo.SizeOfStruct = Marshal.SizeOf(moduleInfo);
if (!SymGetModuleInfo64(_processPtr, _baseOfDll, ref moduleInfo))
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());


That struct looks a bit wrong, CVData should be a LPStr not a ByValTStr, you probably also want to check that FieldOffset of 580 is correct even after adding padding.

Just to verify: your function ConvertToManaged does not throw, it only throws after returning? Also your Unmanaged struct needs to at the very least allocate enough space for all that data, even if you aren't reading it, otherwise your stack will get clobbered.

That's correct, ConvertToManaged does not throw and I'm getting back the data I am expecting. I assumed that Unmanaged doesn't need to be fully fleshed out since it carries the full length of the struct under SizeOfStruct when going in. I am fairly certain I tried allocating the full size prior to the PInvoke call (I've been at it for a while) and it didn't make a difference. I'll try again, then update.


I assumed that Unmanaged doesn't need to be fully fleshed out since it carries the full length of the struct under SizeOfStruct when going in.

You can't just ignore the rest of the data in the struct. You are telling the native function that 1680 (?) bytes are available to be written, but there are actually far less. So C# didn't allocate enough space, meaning you are getting a buffer overrun, wiping out the rest of your stack and probably your return pointer and parameters along with it. Then when you try to assign the ref value, the ref location has been overwritten with garbage or zeroes, so you get an AVE.
At the very least, add a reserved field at the end, or set the struct size explicitly:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 1680)]
public ref struct Unmanaged
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public int SizeOfStruct;
    [FieldOffset(580)] public fixed byte LoadedPdbName[256];
}

The best thing would be to just redefine the whole struct again with all the correct buffers, along with associated reading and copying of the values you need.
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct IMAGEHELP_MODULE64
{
    public int SizeOfStruct;
    public long BaseOfImage;
    public int ImageSize;
    public int TimeDateStamp;
    public int CheckSum;
    public int NumSyms;
    public SymType SymType;

    public fixed byte ModuleName[32];

    public fixed byte ImageName[256];

    public fixed byte LoadedImageName[256];

    public fixed byte LoadedPdbName[256];

    public int CVSig;

    public fixed byte CVData[MAX_PATH * 3];

    public int PdbSig;
    public GUID PdbSig70;
    public int PdbAge;
    public bool PdbUnmatched;
    public bool DbgUnmatched;
    public bool LineNumbers;
    public bool GlobalSymbols;
    public bool TypeInfo;
    public bool SourceIndexed;
    public bool Publics;
    public int MachineType;
    public int Reserved;
}


Thank you, that was it, the Unmanaged struct was too small! I fixed it by setting the size on the StructLayout attribute instead, without having to add extra fields. [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 0x390)].

This is off topic, but I don't think CVData is a pointer after all. With size 0x390 it fails, but size 0x690 works. I searched through github and nobody seems to have it as a pointer either.

I guess the docs are wrong because it has CHAR     *CVData[MAX_PATH  3];
